# Laravel: How to change default login error message: 'these credentials do not match our records'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to change the default login validation error message like:

```
Username & Password doesn't match
```

instead of

```
these credentials do not match our records
```

How to do this ?

Comment: You could have tried searching for that string in your project, and you would have found the file that message is defined yourself…

Comment: Back then, I was just a starter, due to lack of good IDE & command skills I didn't have any idea about it. Hope you understand! @MartinBean

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change this message to another one in this file:

```
resources/lang/en/auth.php
```

This is the line:

```
'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 2):

In `app/Http/controllers/Auth/LoginController` add below code:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
           'username or password is incorrect!!!'
        ]);
}
```

In the `sendFailedLoginResponse` function you can redirect user to custom page or show error alert.

Answer (score 0):

do one thing make new file message.php in lang folder then enter the error message in that and access in the controller and where you want to use like this 
in Authonticateduser.php

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request) {
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ? : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())->with('status', Lang::get('messege.login_success'));
}
```

and you get the perfect mesege you want instead of system mesege and without any change in default message.